# RecylerView onClickListener works on all fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have implemented a recyclerview in my activity and I added a onclick listener to recently. It was working fine, until I switch over to another fragment and realized the click was also working there so if I pressed randomly somewhere on the screen it would bring me the item click in the recycler view. Please let me know how can I only make the recyclerview be clickable on one activity, the home page and no the other.

HomePage.class

```
package com.example.movieapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    RecyclerView recylerView;
    MovieAdapter mainAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recylerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        recylerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("movie"), Model.class)
                        .build();

        mainAdapter = new MovieAdapter(options);
        recylerView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this::onNavigationItemSelected);


        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);


        toggle.syncState();
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new HomeFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
               // Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), UserProfile.class);
               // startActivity(intent);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cart:

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new CartFragment()).commit();
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mainAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mainAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

MovieAdapter.class

```
public class MovieAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model,MovieAdapter.myViewHolder> {




    /**
     * Initialize a {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that listens to a Firebase query. See
     * {@link FirebaseRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    public MovieAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder myViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Model model) {
        myViewHolder.name.setText(model.getName());
        myViewHolder.shortDesc.setText(model.getShortDesc());
        myViewHolder.release.setText(model.getRelease());

        Glide.with(myViewHolder.img.getContext()).load(model.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .error(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal)
                .into(myViewHolder.img);


        myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (view.getContext(), MovieDetails.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                String test =  model.getName() + " Selected";

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), test ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_item, parent, false);
        return new myViewHolder(view);
    }

    class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView img;
        TextView name,shortDesc,release;

        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nametext);
            shortDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shortDesctext);
            release = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.releasetext);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in every time you used this adapter because the onclicklistener is always working, to change this you can create your own custom listener interface,
so you can control to add it or not

```java
public interface OnModelClickListener {
    void onClick(Model model);
}
```

You need to create the instance in the adapter and setter for it

```
private OnModelClickListener onModelClickListener

public void setOnModelClickListener(OnModelClickListener listener) (
    this.onModelClickListener = listener;
}
```

and inside onBindViewHolder you will run this listener if it is not null

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder myViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Model model) {
    myViewHolder.name.setText(model.getName());
    myViewHolder.shortDesc.setText(model.getShortDesc());
    myViewHolder.release.setText(model.getRelease());

    Glide.with(myViewHolder.img.getContext()).load(model.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .error(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal)
                .into(myViewHolder.img);

    if (onModelClickListener != null) {
        myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            onModelClickListener.onClick(model)
        });
    }
}
```

In fragment that you want the listener to work on it, you will use the setter

```java
adapter.setOnModelClickListener(model -> {
    Intent intent = new Intent (view.getContext(), MovieDetails.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    String test =  model.getName() + " Selected";

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), test ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

    startActivity(intent);
});
``
```

Comment: Alright understood, just one question where exactly would I add the onmodelclicklistener method, like which class.

Comment: onmodelclicklistener and the setter will be in the adapter itself so we can call onClick when view.OnclickListener works

Comment: hey for the last code, the one where you want the listener to work in the fragment, which function should I add code to? is it to the onCreate method

Comment: Add it when you initialize the adapter, just initialize it and then call setOnModelClickListener

Comment: appreciate the help, but I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: What is the current state? working in all fragments or not working at all

Comment: The 3rd chunk of code you wrote is giving me errors, I tried using it another way and then it just kept working in all fragments.

Comment: What is the error message

Comment: there are two errors, 1. Cannot resolve symbol 'onClick' and the other one 2. Unknown class: 'model'.

Comment: Do you put this code in the adapter class indie onBindViewHolder?? onClick is the interface function name and model is onBindViewHolder last parameter

Comment: yep, I put it in the onBindViewHolder in the MovieAdapter Class. I also added the onclick interface function in the same class.

Comment: I have updated the chunk and replaced it with full method code please check it again

Comment: I tried it and it's giving me the same error, https://imgur.com/I0BRcYe please take a look for urself. And see if I might have done something wrong. Also thanks.

Comment: I have updated the code because i mixed between new interface and lambda expression, check if again please

Comment: Oops i made a mistake, its working now but the click is still working on all the fragments unfortunately.

Comment: try to rebuild the project and it will be helpful it you can share screenshot for myViewHolder.itemView

Comment: Oops i made a mistake, its working now but the click is still working on all the fragments unfortunately.

Comment: Make sure setOnModeClickListener is used only on the fragment you want the listener to work and make sure your adapter did't use any other listener

Comment: Would it be wrong if I added it into the onCreate for HomePage class? https://imgur.com/jVZLpJV  please take a look what I am currently doing.

Comment: Sorry for delay, now it not problem you can deal with it like any click listener

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I decided to switch from fragments to just use activities instead. And now the recycler view click only works in the class that I want it to. I really appreciate the help, as this is for my school project and was struggling a lot at this part.